# Use external BLAS and LAPACK libraries in a MATLAB mex file

Tags: c, matlab, dynamic-linking

I am currently try to build an interface for a numerical software library to MATLAB. Thereby I end up with the following problem:

MATLAB uses per default 64 bit integers and its BLAS and LAPACK library (namely the MKL) supports only 64 bit integers as well. Unfortunately the library which I want to connect via a mex-file to Matlab uses only 32bit integers and its dependencies too. Whenever the mex-file now tries to call a function from BLAS or LAPACK it crashes because of the different integer widths.

I try to link my mex-file against my own BLAS and LAPACK versions with 32bit integers using

```
mex  myinterface.c -largeArrayDims -llapack -lblas
```

The linker includes the reference to both libraries in the mex file, but if I call it now from MATLAB it crashes. From the backtrace I got that one LAPACK call produces a segementation fault which seems to be cause by the different Integer widths. Furthermore the backtrace tells me that the MKL caused this error instead of the BLAS and LAPACK I linked to my program.

The question is: Is there a possibility to link the mex file to its dependencies such that it resolves the symbols from it instead of the ones from MATLAB, i.e. uses the given BLAS and LAPACK libraries?

remarks:

- MATLAB 2013
- GCC 4.6
- BLAS and LAPACK libraries are dynamical.

Comment: By default Matlab uses 64-bit f-p numbers. An assignment such as `a = 23` leaves `a` a double.  Have you had any success using Matlab's other types, *eg* `a = int32(23)` ?

Comment: The problem is not with the floating point numbers it is with the integers. Matlab and its libraries uses 64 bit integers. The library it want to connect to Matlab is only aware of 32bit integers. The data I got from MATLAB is converted before I call any function in my mex file. But each call to a BLAS function rely un 32 bit integers instead of 64 bit and because BLAS is Fortran based everything passed to a function is a pointer and then there is a difference between accesing a 64 or 32 bit integer.

Comment: @Grisu have you changed env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your 32bit libraries?

Comment: The system is a 64 bit architecture and the separate BLAS and LAPACK libraries I want to are 64 bit binaries too although they deal only with 32 bit integers. The problem is that runtime linker did not load the symbols from BLAS and LAPACK because they are already known in the address space because they are provided by Matlab and the MKL. But I have to enforce that the ones I link will be used.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is what you think.. First of all, 64-bit applications can only load 64-bit shared libraries. But if you meant that `mwIndex` and `mwSize` types defined by MATLAB being 32 vs 64-bits, then try compiling with `mex -compatibleArrayDims ..`. This will force 32-bit integers as default sizes even on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: also during compilation, if you do not specifically specify your own paths, the linker will be looking at MATLAB's own versions of BLAS/LAPACK instead of your own. So use something like: `mex -v -I/path/to/include -L/path/to/libs ...`, possibly even `mex -v CFLAGS='-I... -Wall $CFLAGS' LDFLAGS='-L.. -w $LDFLAGS'` to be more sure (or any other GCC options to make it more verbose)

Comment: A final note: I remember that it was once possible to even replace the BLAS/LAPACK implementations loaded for the entire MATLAB session (I think it was controlled by either environment variables, or a config file somewhere), so you could bypass Intel MKL libraries and load your own (ATLAS, OpenBLAS, etc...). But I'm not sure its possible anymore, so don't quote me on that :)

Comment: This is the one I was referring to: http://www.stanford.edu/~echu508/matlab.html . Personally I've never done this.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a year old already, but this might be useful for somebody:

I believe your problem would be solved if you pre-loaded dynamically linked libraries to enforce their use (maybe along with changing your LD_LIBRARY_PATH as Shai has suggested). I had to do something similar to enforce use of particular versions of some libraries. LD_LIBRARY_PATH works for *external* libraries (such as OpenCV), while LD_PRELOAD for *standard* libraries. On your command line, type the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/OpenCV/lib/:/path/to/SomethingElse/lib
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16:/path/to/libOtherStandardLibrary.so
matlab
```

This helps also with the problem of stdc++ having different version for the system and for Matlab (which carries its own, older, version).